# Why did main class reported cannot be found or loaded when using import-csv.bat to import data into Apache IoTDB version 1.3?

Tags: import, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am trying to use csv import tool `import-csv.bat` included in Apache IoTDB. I am now in Windows environment, but when running `import-csv.bat`, the system reports that the main class cannot be found or the main class cannot be loaded. The current IoTDB version is 1.3. Does anyone use this version to import data and what settings do I need to change to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `classpath` field in `import-csv.bat` configuration of Apache IoTDB, and see if it is not wrapped with double quotes, which should be the reason for your error. Just wrap the `classpath` in the bat file with double quotes, and the problem should be solved.